# How to get a reference for Gmail Inbox button?

Tags: javascript, gmail

I want to get a reference to the Gmail Inbox button in Javascript? I tried my code in Firebug console but could not manage to find the right DOM node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Array.prototype.filter.call(
  document.getElementById("canvas_frame").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a"),
  function(x){return /#inbox$/.test(x.href);}
)[0];
```